# Batch Drawable Import in android studio crashes studio

Tags: android, plugins, android-drawable, android-studio-3.6.1

When importing drawable using batch drawable importer plugin, studio crashes and the drawable is not being created.
Using Android Studio 3.6.1
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Before it was working correctly

Comment: show logcat please.

Comment: Yes, I am having the same issue with Android Studio 3.6 and 3.6.1. I have to keep 2 Android Studio in my system, 3.6.1 for work and 3.5.3 for batch drawable plugin

Comment: Actually , I can't create a drawable.When the generate button is clicked Studio crashes .No log, only report.  -IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded studio to 4.+ even after that the issue was still there.The intellij plugin is actually deprecated now , so if we are again trying to get result using that plugin, it will only crash the studio. So instead I downloaded the plugin from this link https://gpskaihu.nz/ADI-hack/
When installing remove already installed plugin, then restart the studio.
Then add the downloaded plugin to studio and restart studio.
You are ready to go..